# [Vue warn]: Vue received a Component which was made a reactive object NUXT

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

How can I solve this problem. there is no solution to this problem on this forum.
I'm use latest version nuxt.
`<Icon width="20" height="20" />`

```
<template>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" :width="width" :height="height" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
    <g fill="none" stroke="#888888" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="1.5">
      <path d="M17 15h-5m-5-5l.234.195c1.282 1.068 1.923 1.602 1.923 2.305c0 .703-.64 1.237-1.923 2.305L7 15" />
      <path
        d="M22 12c0 4.714 0 7.071-1.465 8.535C19.072 22 16.714 22 12 22s-7.071 0-8.536-1.465C2 19.072 2 16.714 2 12s0-7.071 1.464-8.536C4.93 2 7.286 2 12 2c4.714 0 7.071 0 8.535 1.464c.974.974 1.3 2.343 1.41 4.536"
      />
    </g>
  </svg>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    width: {
      type: String,
      default: "1rem"
    },
    height: {
      type: String,
      default: "1rem"
    }
  },
};
</script>
<style lang="scss" scoped></style>
```

error:[Vue warn]: Vue received a Component which was made a reactive object. This can lead to unnecessary performance overhead, and should be avoided by marking the component with `markRaw` or using `shallowRef` instead of `ref`.

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem. Since the component you posted doesn't contain other components, it's unlikely it caused the problem, but the way it's used could